# Is using rownum with a presorted result good or should rank be used?

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, rownum

I'm writing an Oracle query that needs to get the most recent event based on the date it occurred.

I have two queries that appear to be working correctly in my test cases.

The first uses a subquery to get the events in date order and then I just pull the first record via rownum:

```
    SELECT description FROM
    (
     SELECT description FROM tablename
     WHERE ((event_type IN ('A','I','Y')) AND (meeting_date IS NOT NULL) 
     AND id='whatever') 
     ORDER BY meeting_date DESC
    )
    WHERE rownum = 1
```

The second one uses rank to accomplish the same result:

```
SELECT description FROM
(
SELECT description, RANK() OVER( ORDER BY meeting_date DESC) mtg_rank 
 FROM tablename 
 WHERE ((event_type IN ('A','I','Y'))  AND (meeting_date IS NOT NULL) 
 AND id= 'whatever') 
)
WHERE mtg_rank = 1
```

To me the presorted rownum is simple enough and I would go with it.  I realize that rownum works before a sort which is why I did the ordering in a subselect first.

However, I'm not sure if I'm missing something with that thought?

I am also wondering if rank in this case is the preferred/best practice or perhaps is better at conveying the intent of the query?

Comment: Your two queries may give different results if there are ties (that is, two rows with the same value of MEETING_DATE).  The first query will return at most one row.  The second query may return more than one row if there are ties (since the RANK will be the same for both rows).  The ROW_NUMBER analytic function is a closer analog to ROWNUM.  The choice between RANK and ROWNUM/ROW_NUMBER depends on how you want to handle ties.

Comment: OH: I didn't think about ties.... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for cases of ties (which Brian's comment discusses quite well), both queries will work and will return the same results.

Personally, I would much prefer the analytic function approach because it is much more adaptable.  You can adjust how ties are handled by swapping between the `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, and `ROW_NUMBER` analytic functions.  You can also do things like add a `PARTITION BY` clause to return the most recent meeting for each `ID` if you want to run the query for multiple `ID` values rather than just one.

Comment: Lots to think about but I believe you have given me the answer I was looking for.  The analytical functions are designed for this and thus just by mere intent should be seen as more desirable to use.  Not to mention handling ties if needed. :-)